# Difference Between indexOf and findIndex function of array

Tags: javascript

I am confused between the difference between the two function indexOf and find Index in an  array.

The documentation says

> findIndex - Returns the index of the first element in the array where
>   predicate is true, and -1 otherwise.

and

> indexOf - Returns the index of the first occurrence of a value in an
>   array.

Comment: I think the difference is, one takes a function as an argument (enabling more sophisticated finds, like say you were looking for the first occurrence of a value with a specific substring instead of just the whole value), one just takes the value you're looking for. It's actually not a bad question. Downvotes without explanation should be down-votable.

Comment: Sometimes it's best to start with the language specification (i.e. ECMA-262) and fill in the gaps with other material: [*Array.prototype.indexOf ( searchElement \[ , fromIndex \] )*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.indexof) vs [*Array.prototype.findIndex ( predicate \[ , thisArg \] )*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.findindex).

Answer (score 384, accepted):

The main difference are the parameters of these functions:

- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) expects a *value* as first parameter. This makes it a good choice to find the index in arrays of [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) (like string, number, or boolean).
- [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) expects a *callback* as first parameter. Use this if you need the index in arrays with non-primitive types (e.g. objects) or your find condition is more complex than just a value.

See the links for examples of both cases.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering what primitive types are js, they are things like  string, number, boolean.

Comment: Please note that `indexOf` will work to find objects. It is important to get the distinction that it accepts a single Object, not just a value, and compares by equality not value.

Per Mozilla docs:

```indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator).```

Please amend the `findIndex` explanation to only include the "or your find condition is more complex than just a single value or reference" limb to correct this as it led me astray originally. Thanks!

Comment: @brokenalarms That is true, but only if you have a reference to an actual object in the array. For example, `[{a:1}].indexOf({a:1})` returns `-1` although the object seems to be the same (but it is not). Not sure whether this information is helpful in the answer as it might be confusing. If you need to know more about the exact language behaviour, you should read the specification.

Comment: Furthermore, indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator).

Comment: Worth noting however that `.indexOf(NaN)` will always return `-1` because `NaN==NaN` is always `false`. `NaN` *is* a primitive type because `typeof NaN` is `number` and so are `null` and `undefined`, so I would amend this to avoid saying `indexOf` works on primitive types

Comment: @Matthew It does work on primitive types that are equal to themselves.

Answer (score 34):

Simple - What kind of array structure are you using?

- If array of objects, `findIndex()`;
- Else, `indexOf()`.

"I want to find the index in an **array of objects**, with the key of "Orange".

```
let fruits = [
   { type: "Apple", quantity: 9 },
   { type: "Banana", quantity: 2},
   { type: "Orange", quantity: 8},
   { type: "Pear", quantity: 777}
];

let myIndex = fruits.findIndex(fruit => fruit.type === "Orange"); // Returns 2.
```

"I want to find the index in a **simple array**".

```
let fruits = [ "Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Orange"];

let index = fruits.indexOf("Orange"); // Returns 3.
```

Answer (score 21):

FindIndex is useful if you want to find the first element that matches to your predicate: In W3C's example, there are numbers and matches if the customer's age above or equals to 18.

```
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];

function checkAdult(age) {
    return age >= 18;
}

console.log(ages.findIndex(checkAdult));
```

console:

```
2
```

You can find an exact element index with the indexOf function of Array, but you can't pass a predicate. It is faster if you want to find a specific element:

```
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];
console.log(ages.indexOf(10));
```

returns:

```
1
```

Index counting starts at 0, so the first element index is 0.

Answer (score 19):

The main difference between these is:

> The findIndex() method gets a callback function like this:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
x.findIndex(x=> x==3); //returns 2
```

> But the indexOf function gets just a value like this:

```
x.indexOf(3); // returns 2;
```

> If you try to pass a callback into the indexOf it's return -1;

```
x.indexOf(x => x==3); //returns -1
```

> And if try to pass value to findIndex it returns an error:

```
x.findIndex(3); //Uncaught TypeError: 3 is not a function at Array.findIndex (<anonymous>) at <anonymous>:1:3
```

Answer (score 6):

Another difference is that 
with ***findIndex()*** the user ***can apply some function*** and find the element in the array which passes the test.

But the same is not true with ***indexOf()*** operator.
A user can just check whether the particular element exists in the array or not.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `includes`:

```
[1, 2, 3].includes(2);      // true
[1, 2, 3].includes(4);      // false
[1, 2, 3].includes(3, 3);   // false
```

but I prefer the `indexOf` method:

```
var vals = [ "foo", "bar", 42, "baz" ];
if (~vals.indexOf( 42 )) {
  // found it!
}
```

Comment: also includes requires a polyfill for IE

Comment: `indexOf` is much faster as well.

Answer (score 5):

**The main difference are the parameters of these functions:**

->
**Array.prototype.indexOf()** :

```
   var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
   var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
   The result of a will be: 2
```

->**Array.prototype.findIndex()** :

```
       var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];

       function checkAdult(age) {
        return age >= 18;
       }

       function myFunction() {
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
         ages.findIndex(checkAdult);
       }

       The result will be: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the codes below:-

```
let city = ['Delhi', 'mumbai']
const a = city.findIndex((item) => 
item.toLowerCase()==='delhi')
console.log(a) // returns 0

let c = city.indexOf('mumbai') // returns 1
console.log(c)
```

Comment: I don't think this code requires any explanation because this code looks very simple & easy to understand for a 'beginner' . Also, people who are beginners they face difficulty to understand complex code so I made it simple. So please don't say it low quality without understanding my intention.

Comment: I didn't find anything low quality marked by system.

Answer (score 1):

- `findIndex` accepts a callback as parameter and is best used with arrays of objects.

```
const employees = [
  { id: 1, name: "John", dob: 1999 },
  { id: 2, name: "Doe", dob: 2005 },
  { id: 3, name: "Marry", dob: 2001 },
  { id: 4, name: "Larry", dob: 1990 },
]

const output = employees.findIndex((elem) => elem.name === "Doe") // 1
```

- `indexOf` accepts a value as a parameter.

```
let alphabets = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
alphabets.indexOf("c") // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is **whether we can use conditions(boolean) to find an element's index**.

`.indexOf()` can't have callback function as an argument(condition) to find an element's index.

`.findIndex()` can have callback function that returns boolean value (conditions) to find the first element's index that matches.

for example,

```
const names = ["John", "Princess", "Dominik", "Jay"];

// when we want to find an index of 'Jay'
const indexOfExample = names.indexOf("Jay");

// when we want to find an index of an element that has 4 or less characters
const findIndexExample = names.findIndex(function isShortName(name) {
    return name.length <= 4; 
})

// when we want to find an index of an element that has 7 or more characters
const findIndexExample2 = names.findIndex(name=>name.length>=7); 

console.log(indexOfExample) // 3
console.log(findIndexExample) // 0
console.log(findIndexExample2) // 1
```