# Javascript - JSON file returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

For some reason when I try and call my command it returns `[object Object],[object, Object]`

```
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "../moderation") + "/modlogs.json", "utf-8", function(err, data) { // read the JSON file
  if (err) throw err; // throw error if applicable

var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(data); // parse the data

for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.warns.length; i++) { // loop through all keys in warns file
  if (arrayOfObjects.warns[i].user_id === user.id) { // check if the user has already been warned
    message.reply("User already warned. Kicking user."); // display kick
    //message.guild.member(user).kick(); // kicks member
    indexOfUser = arrayOfObjects.warns.findIndex(x => x.user_id == user.id); // find the index of the users object
    //message.channel.sendMessage(indexOfUser);
    message.channel.sendMessage("Before splicing" + arrayOfObjects.warns);
    //arrayOfObjects.warns.splice(indexOfUser, 1); // remove the user from warns array
    message.channel.sendMessage("After splicing" + arrayOfObjects.warns);
    return;
  };
};
```

The line `//arrayOfObjects.warns.splice(indexOfUser, 1); // remove the user from warns array` is supposed to delete that object from the `warns` array in my JSON file. However it doesn't, the `console.log`s were just to see what was getting outputed, and it seems like the values aren't getting through.

Comment: please provide a sample of the JSON string you get as `data`.

Comment: i don't see where you're returning anything at all. What's giving you that output? That output only happens when you try to convert something that is an object to a string.

Comment: is there something new?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using findIndex() instead indexOf() when you try to find the index.

[Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) expects a value as first parameter. This makes it a good choice to find the index in arrays of primitive types.

[Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) expects a callback as first parameter. Use this if you need the index in arrays with non-primitive types (e.g. objects) or your find condition is more complex than just a value.

See the links for examples of both cases.
info from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41443138/7733724)

Edit:

I bring you some usefull code.

**With indexOf()**

```
  if (arrayOfObjects.warns.indexOf(user_id) > -1) { // check if the user has already been warned

    message.reply("User already warned. Kicking user."); // display kick
    //message.guild.member(user).kick(); // kicks member

    indexOfUser = arrayOfObjects.warns.indexOf(user_id);

    //message.channel.sendMessage(indexOfUser);
    message.channel.sendMessage("Before splicing" + arrayOfObjects.warns);
    //arrayOfObjects.warns.splice(indexOfUser, 1); // remove the user from warns array
    message.channel.sendMessage("After splicing" + arrayOfObjects.warns);
    return;
  };
```

*Aclaration*: indexOf(value) returns -1 if it can't find the item in the Array. Otherwise it returns the index where item is located. So you don't need to iterate in the array.

**with findIndex()**

When using findIndex() you don't define the value you want to find in the array. You define the function that will be executed every iteration.

You could do something like:

```
function iswarned (elem) {
 return elem.user_id == user_id;
}

 if (arrayOfObjects.warns.findIndex(iswarned) > -1) {
   indexOfUser = arrayOfObjects.warns.findIndex(iswarned);
}
```

*Aclaration:* findIndex() returns the first index for what callback function returns a truthy value or -1  If the callback never returns a truthy value or array.length is 0.

Comment: indexOf() returns the same thing.

Comment: anyways is not actually i the index you need to remove?

Comment: edited my first answer I added a little code to see if it works for you.