# Add and remove values inside array in change event of checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular6

In my angular application, i am making a checkbox and capturing the checkbox change event and pushing the checked value into array..

Here if we uncheck the checkbox also the obj were pushed to the array..

How to **remove** the **obj** from array if **uncheck** the checkbox..

Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of order; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" [id]="item+i" [name]="item"[(ngModel)]="item.Checked" (change)="getCheckboxValues(item)">
   <label [for]="item+i"> {{item}} </label>
</div>
```

Ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  order = ['One','Two','Three','Four'];

  newArray : any = [];

  //Checkbox Change detecting function
  getCheckboxValues(data) {
    let obj = {
      "order" : data
    }

   // Pushing the object into array
    this.newArray.push(obj);

    //Duplicates the obj if we uncheck it
    //How to remove the value from array if we uncheck it
    console.log(this.newArray);
  }

}
```

The thing i have worked out with the above was in the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pt9sn

Kindly help me to remove the unchecked values inside the ``newArray```..

Comment: use reactiveform

Comment: This link would help https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

Comment: @Chellappan, Why bro we can't achieve it like this?? Because i am not going to use form for it and i need to store the values of checked alone..

Comment: @Chellappan, If its good to use reactive form then please post it as solution bro., I will check for it..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8fyfp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to `(ngModelChange)="getCheckboxValues($event,item)"`

and the function to add if not there and remove if the element exist based on check and uncheck of checkbox

```
  //Checkbox Change detecting function
  getCheckboxValues(ev, data) {
    let obj = {
      "order" : data
    }

    if(ev.target.checked){
      // Pushing the object into array
      this.newArray.push(obj);

    }else {
      let removeIndex = this.newArray.findIndex(itm => itm.order===data);

      if(removeIndex !== -1)
        this.newArray.splice(removeIndex,1);
    }

    //Duplicates the obj if we uncheck it
    //How to remove the value from array if we uncheck it
    console.log(this.newArray);
  }
```

Link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5jamcr

Comment: Is it better use find + indexOf?

Comment: good point. I remember the use of findIndex which is find+indexOf

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index along with the object and remove if from the array if the checked status is false;

```
//Checkbox Change detecting function
 getCheckboxValues(data, index) {
    let obj = {
      "order" : data
    }

    if(!data.Checked){
       this.newArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else{

      // Pushing the object into array
      this.newArray.push(obj);
    }


       //Duplicates the obj if we uncheck it
       //How to remove the value from array if we uncheck it
        console.log(this.newArray);
}

<input type="checkbox" [id]="item+i" [name]="item"[(ngModel)]="item.Checked" (change)="getCheckboxValues(item, i)">
```

Comment: I am getting empty array in console.log(this.newArray) if i use the above code (both check and uncheck the checkbox).. Can you make the stackblitz with the above solution??

Comment: I think you should be using the index while pushing as well. because if I click on 3rd checkbox first then it will be in position 0. Check that. it might be the missing piece

Comment: @undefined https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzwjea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Why its not possible without modifying the ```array``` named order ?? You have completly modified the array ```order```.. I can not modify it.. I hope you know that those values will be coming from the service.. Here for better understanding i have hardcoded thse..

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

Change in HTML:

```
(ngModelChange)="getCheckboxValues($event,item)"  // use ndModelChange event
```

and in TS:

```
getCheckboxValues(event, data) {

    // use findIndex method to find the index of checked or unchecked item
    var index = this.newArray.findIndex(x => x.order==data);

    // If checked then push 
    if (event) {
       let obj = {
        "order": data
    }
      // Pushing the object into array
      this.newArray.push(obj);
    }
    else {
      this.newArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
    //Duplicates the obj if we uncheck it
    //How to remove the value from array if we uncheck it
    console.log(this.newArray);
  }
}
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjddew)

You can read about `findIndex` and `indexOf` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41443138/7124761)

Comment: Please check with your example correctly... If i check all four and remove the ```three``` but the array has removed the last value ```four``` and not ```three```..

Comment: @undefined let me check [out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjddew)

Comment: STill it was like that only please check it out thoroughly what happens if you check all four and uncheck ```three``` from it..

Comment: @undefined yes got it... to check out my updated answer and working [ex](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjddew)

Comment: @undefined have used [findIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41443138/7124761) method to find out the index of the particular item