# how to find index of an array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var styles = ['btx btx1', 'btx btx2', 'btx btx3', 'btx btx4'];

$('#mst').on('click', function(){
    let a = $('#btx').attr('class');
    console.log(a);  // `btx btx2`
    let x = styles.findIndex(a);
    console.log(x);  // error
});
```

error -  `Uncaught TypeError: btx btx2 is not a function`

I'm expecting `1` as the result

Comment: I think you meant `indexOf` rather than `findIndex`, which [expects a function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), as the error tells you. VTC as typo/resolved in a way unhelpful to future visitors.

Comment: @ggorlen - what about this - `https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp`

Comment: What about it? It says the same thing as above which is that you need to pass a function to `findIndex`. You could do this with `styles.findIndex(e => e === a);` but this is a more verbose and less efficient way to write `styles.indexOf(a)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use indexOf:

```
$('#mst').on('click', function(){
   let a = $('#btx').attr('class');
   console.log(a);  // `btx btx2`
   let x = styles.indexOf(a);
   console.log(x);  // error
});
```

Comment: what about this - `https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp`

Comment: see this link, explained very well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443029/difference-between-indexof-and-findindex-function-of-array

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [`findIndex()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp), the params must be **function** instead of a specific item.

*Syntax*

```
array.findIndex(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```

```js
var styles = ['btx btx1', 'btx btx2', 'btx btx3', 'btx btx4'];

let a = 'btx btx2';
let x = styles.findIndex(function(currentValue, index, arr){
  return currentValue === a;
});

console.log(x);
```

Or use [`indexOf()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

> The indexOf() method searches the array for the **specified item**, and
>   returns its position.

```js
var styles = ['btx btx1', 'btx btx2', 'btx btx3', 'btx btx4'];

let a = 'btx btx2';
let x = styles.indexOf(a);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: @qadenza Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help