# return the index of new shuffled element

Tags: javascript

Here is what I want:

I have `first` array and I have the `index` as below:

```
const first = ['a','b','c'];
const index = 1; // the index of b

const shuffled = ['c','a','b']; // now the index of b is 2
```

In the `first` array the `index` points to the second element in the array which is `b` right?

Now I shuffled the `first` array and we have the `shuffled` array .

The index of `b` is 2 right now. I want to return this new index...

Comment: shuffled.indexOf('b');

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between indexOf and findIndex function of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443029/difference-between-indexof-and-findindex-function-of-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
const first = ['a','b','c'];
const index = 1;
const shuffled = ['c','a','b'];

const target = first[index];
const newIndex = shuffled.indexOf(target);

console.log(newIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `shuffled.indexOf(first[index])`

`first[index]` returns the value of the `first index` in this case `'b'`

`shuffled.indexOf('b')` would return the index of b in the `shuffled` array

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

Let value = first[index]

let newValue =shuffled.indexof(value)