# indexOf not working correctly in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

my code is :

`[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}].indexOf(obj=>{return obj.a ==1})`

I expect return 0 but result is -1

what is the problem?

Comment: Their arguments

Comment: This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443029/difference-between-indexof-and-findindex-function-of-array) and the answer can also be found there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference are the parameters of these functions:

- Array.prototype.indexOf() expects a value as first parameter. This
  makes it a good choice to find the index in arrays of primitive types
  (like string, number, or boolean).
- Array.prototype.findIndex() expects a callback as first parameter.
  Use this if you need the index in arrays with non-primitive types
  (e.g. objects) or your find condition is more complex than just a
  value.

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443029/difference-between-indexof-and-findindex-function-of-array) and the answer can also be found there.

Comment: If you found a duplicate you can mark the current question as one, no need to answer it again. This can be done by casting a [close vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (requires 3k reputation) or by [flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) it as one (requires 15 reputation)

Comment: @Reyno how could he?